# Emacs: How to kill (C-x 4 0) a buffer of a frame by using the GUI Close button?

Tags: emacs

I know it is a bad habit to use a mouse as an Emacs user. However, there are times when it is just convenient to close "some" of my multiple Emacs frames by clicking the red "x" Close button on the upper left corner of Finder rather than just repeatedly using C-x 4 0.

Is there is a way to rebind OS X GUI Close button to kill (C-x 4 0) the buffer of a frame - that is, kill the buffer and the frame at the same time? And if the buffer has no filename, Emacs will ask me to save or discard the buffer.

My Emacs is 24.3.1 on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is *not* a bad idea to use a mouse with Emacs. Quite the contrary. But it can be a bad *habit*, as you say: anything overdone can be a bad habit. Emacs works especially well with a mouse (the Emacs mouse is more powerful than usual), and it works fine without a mouse. Use a mouse for what it is good for: direct access to any position, just by pointing.

And yes, you can make Emacs perform a command (such as `delete-frame`) when you click the window-manager `X` icon (or whatever icon your window manager uses to delete windows).  You do this:

```
(define-key special-event-map [delete-frame] 'delete-frame)
```

See [`(elisp) Special Events`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Events.html#Special-Events).

(In library [`thumb-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/thumb-frm.el) I use the Minimize icon (optionally) to thumbify frames, as another example of this.)

---

To answer your comment question more specifically. This code prompts for the buffer to kill (default: current buffer).  If there is only one frame, then it quits Emacs.  Otherwise, it deletes only the selected frame.

```
(defun foo (&optional buffer)
  (interactive (list (read-buffer "Buffer: " (current-buffer))))
  (if (not (cadr (frame-list)))
      (save-buffers-kill-terminal) ; Kill Emacs, if last frame
    (kill-buffer buffer)
    (delete-frame (selected-frame) 'FORCE)))

(define-key special-event-map [delete-frame] 'foo)
```

Comment: I tried that line of code, it can close the frame but will not kill the buffer running in the background. Is there a way to close the frame and also kill the buffer at the same time? That can save me from using a lot of C-x 4 0 to close many buffers opened up in many frames. I will keep some buffers opened up in frames so I did not consider macro. Thanks.

Comment: What buffer? A frame can show multiple buffers. If you know what buffer it is, then just write a command `foo` that does both: (a) kills the buffer and (b) deletes the frame. Then use `foo` in place of the second occurrence of *delete-frame* in the code above. The first occurrence refers to the key sequence (which is clicking the close icon in this case). The second occurrence is whatever command you want to execute.

Comment: By the way, are you the inventor of icicles?

Comment: Yes.    [filler to reach comment minimum]

Comment: Okay. I've got a lot of questions to ask you about <mouse-2> stuff for Mac users. I will open a new question later.

Comment: Send me email, if you want to discuss something or file a bug report. This is not the best place for such things. See file headers for contact info. Oh, and I don't use a Mac, so I might not be able to help with Mac mouse-2 questions.

Comment: The code kind of works but not quite the way I want it.

Suppose I have frame#2 and frame#10. When I click Close of frame#10, then the prompt asking me is in the minibuffer of frame2, not frame#10. Ideally, if I click close of any frame, be it frame#5 or frame#6, the minibuffer should be prompted under the current frame to be closed.

Comment: The minibuffer used is likely the one associated with the current buffer or the window that is selected when you click the X. Experiment by clicking a window in the frame you want to delete etc. Then you can add code to switch to the window or buffer you want first.